# Eclipse cannot launch android emulator on Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, emulation, android-virtual-device

When I try to launch an android emulator using AVD from Eclipse, it shows an error.

> Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/mahdi/Desktop/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917/sdk//tools/emulator": error=2, No such file or directory

I think the problem is in the address. Because it has 2 slashes before "tools" folder.

> //tools

I think it should be this or it has something to do with my operating system. I'm working on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change android sdk location from eclipse using window->prefrences->Android

Comment: It's not that. SDK location is alright. as i said the problem is in the address. it can't find the folder "tools".